# Performing a multi value LIKE on the result of a CASE WHEN SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, sql-like

Is it possible to perform a multiple valued LIKE (LIKE "x" OR "y" ..) on the result of a CASE WHEN.

What I'd like to achieve:

```
((CASE WHEN customerName IS NULL THEN "abc" ELSE "def" END) LIKE "a" OR "b" or "d")
```

What I'd like to avoid doing:

```
((CASE WHEN customerName IS NULL THEN "abc" ELSE "def" END) LIKE "a") 
OR ((CASE WHEN customerName IS NULL THEN "abc" ELSE "def" END) LIKE "b") 
OR ((CASE WHEN customerName IS NULL THEN "abc" ELSE "def" END) LIKE "c")
```

Comment: Consider a CTE or a derived table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `~` operator in order to execute a regex like expression. 
For example, Let's say that you have the following values:

```
'abc'
'qabc'
'ptestp'
'sometext'
'oneone'
```

If you want to select only the ones that contain `abc` or `test` you can execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('abc'),
                      ('qabc'),
                      ('ptestp'),
                      ('sometext'),
                      ('oneone'))
example_data(label)
WHERE label ~ 'abc|test';
```

This will only select the following values:
`abc`, `qabc`, `ptestp`.

Remember that the `~` operator accepts a regex on the right side, so you can use any kind of patterns (like full matching, matching at the beginning of word, at the end of the word and etc).

For example the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('abc'),
                      ('abcc'),
                      ('ptestp'),
                      ('sometext'),
                      ('oneone'))
example_data(label)
WHERE label ~ '^abc$|^test$';
```

Will select only the first row (`abc`) because it requires that the words fully match.

Comment: you can also make that case insensitive with ~*

Comment: What does the example_data refer to in this case?

Comment: `example_data` is the name of the table that I am creating with the `VALUES` statement. The values statement (in the example) creates a table with one column and 4 rows ('abc', 'abcc', 'ptestp', 'sometext', 'oneone'). I am naming that table `example_data` and the only column that the table contains is named `label`.

Comment: @Dvorog I'll test this method out and give you some feedback.

Comment: @ImErvin Hi Ervin, did you have any problems with the answer I offered ? If yes, I could try to expand my answer and include more examples.

Comment: @Dvorog Hey sorry for the late reply, your answer was very helpful thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can join main query with subquery. Check This:

> ```
> select customerName from 
> (
>   select 'fff' customerName union all
>   select null
> ) customer
> where exists ( 
>   select 1 from
>   (
>     select 'a' x union all
>     select 'b' union all
>     select 'd'
>   ) i
>   where (CASE WHEN customerName IS NULL THEN 'abc' ELSE 'def' END) LIKE i.X || '%'
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> | customername |
> | :----------- |
> | fff          |
> | null         |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7e0e71aa91cacb8e036768e7d7a337e9)*